# Target dynamically added button with jquery (no event)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know a way to disable and undisable, using Jquery, a dynamically added html button.

I'm aware of the .on() function, but in order to work, this function need and event to listen to (like a click or something) and I don't have any event to bind cause i'm calling it from a function.

This is the actual code, wich it's not working cause the button with "#myID" is a partial which has been injected dynamically after the document ready():

```
 var validateForm = function(){
    if(exp_valid && cc_valid && ch_valid && cvn_valid){
        $('#myID').prop('disabled', false);
    }
 }
```

I would like a proper way to select, with no event, my dynamically added button.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: This is easy, you just have to wait for the button to be there, you can't change something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Selecting dynamically added elements is no different from selecting any other element. If it exists in the document, you can select it. If you have an issue, provide an actual reproduction of that issue.

Comment: I can target my button and this works $('#myID').show();
But im not able to enable nor disable my button, the prop('disabled', true) should work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it using :

```
  $('#myID').attr("disabled", true);
```

Thank you everyone for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the button exists first

```
if ($(#myID).length) {
  $('#myID').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Comment: $('#myID).length is returning 1, but I still can't disable or enable my button.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is set a `MutationObserver` to watch for changes on your DOM elements, that way you can trigger a new check if something was added to your node tree.

Simplified JS:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
  // This is where you run your function
  $('#myID').attr("disabled", true);
  console.log($('#myID'));
});

observer.observe(document.documentElement, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true            
});
```

I've put together [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/4fhedchh/), where a button is added dynamically and you can run your function again to check whether it should be disabled or not.

The full implementation is really well described in this article: http://ryanmorr.com/using-mutation-observers-to-watch-for-element-availability/

Comment: Thank you for sharing this approach and ressources. This is wonderful !